# Error in Groovy/Grails tool suite with grails project

Tags: grails, windows-7-x64

Hi i am new to Groovy/Grails and i recently installed Groovy/Grails suite 3.6.4 on windows 7. I made my JAVA_HOME and GRAIL_HOME and when i tried to run a Grails application i get the following errors.

```
   Error 
|
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\οΏ½οΏ½οΏ½\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.grails.ide.eclipse.core\as-dependencies.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
Error |
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
Error |
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
Error |
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
Error |
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.DependencyFileFormat$DepWriter.<init>(DependencyFileFormat.java:55)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.shared.DependencyFileFormat.write(DependencyFileFormat.java:106)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.writeDependencyFile(GrailsBuildSettingsDependencyExtractor.java:206)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.writeDependencyFile(GrailsProcess.java:200)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:133)
Error |
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
```

Comment: Did you check out if specified file (`C:\Users\οΏ½οΏ½οΏ½\Documents\workspace-ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.grails.ide.eclipse.core\as-dependencies.txt`) exist? Moreover did you try to move GGTS to another location, where it won't have problems with non-utf string in filepath (f.e. from `C:\Users\οΏ½οΏ½οΏ½\...` to `C:\worksapces\...`?

Comment: it was actually the non-utf string problem ty.